# "name 'net' is not defined" in endoder4editing neural network (not my code)

Tags: python, neural-network

I am trying to run this code in google drive as it instructs: https://colab.research.google.com/github/bycloudai/StyleCLIP-e4e-colab/blob/main/notebooks/e4e%2BStyleCLIPglobal.ipynb

I didn't write this or edit the code at all.

Copied it to my google drive, provided an image and tried running the code. Getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-f7be2c195159> in <module>()
     16 with torch.no_grad():
     17     tic = time.time()
---> 18     images, latents = run_on_batch(transformed_image.unsqueeze(0), net)
     19     result_image, latent = images[0], latents[0]
     20     toc = time.time()

NameError: name 'net' is not defined
```

This is the code giving the error:

```
#@title
img_transforms = EXPERIMENT_ARGS['transform']
transformed_image = img_transforms(input_image)

def display_alongside_source_image(result_image, source_image):
    res = np.concatenate([np.array(source_image.resize(resize_dims)),
                          np.array(result_image.resize(resize_dims))], axis=1)
    return Image.fromarray(res)

def run_on_batch(inputs, net):
    images, latents = net(inputs.to("cuda").float(), randomize_noise=False, return_latents=True)
    if experiment_type == 'cars_encode':
        images = images[:, :, 32:224, :]
    return images, latents

with torch.no_grad():
    tic = time.time()
    images, latents = run_on_batch(transformed_image.unsqueeze(0), net)
    result_image, latent = images[0], latents[0]
    toc = time.time()
    print('Inference took {:.4f} seconds.'.format(toc - tic))

# Display inversion:
display_alongside_source_image(tensor2im(result_image), input_image)
```

There are 4 code blocks in this portion and it seems like it's been showing a later error.

New error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnpicklingError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-12a54160f322> in <module>()
      1 #@title
      2 model_path = EXPERIMENT_ARGS['model_path']
----> 3 ckpt = torch.load(model_path, map_location='cpu')
      4 opts = ckpt['opts']
      5 # pprint.pprint(opts)  # Display full options used

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/serialization.py in _legacy_load(f, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
    762             "functionality.")
    763 
--> 764     magic_number = pickle_module.load(f, **pickle_load_args)
    765     if magic_number != MAGIC_NUMBER:
    766         raise RuntimeError("Invalid magic number; corrupt file?")

UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '<'.
```

Code:

```
#@title
model_path = EXPERIMENT_ARGS['model_path']
ckpt = torch.load(model_path, map_location='cpu')
opts = ckpt['opts']
# pprint.pprint(opts)  # Display full options used
# update the training options
opts['checkpoint_path'] = model_path
opts= Namespace(**opts)
net = pSp(opts)
net.eval()
net.cuda()
print('Model successfully loaded!')
```

Comment: Have you run the cell where `net` is defined? And has it finished successfully?

Comment: @JohnColeman It's linked directly from a video that shows it working.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Yeah I ran the code sections in sequence as it says and they worked.